# Jquery Form Plugin - Retain input values if form fails to send

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using the jquery form plugin ([from malsup](https://github.com/malsup/form/)) and it's working great. The problem i am having is that if there is an error on the form (like if one required field is left blank) the entire form resets.

How can i make the input fields retain their values if they have been filled in even if one of the required fields is left blank?

A great example is used on this site: I tried to post this question but forgot to add tags, but it kept the original input (like my message and title).

Answer (score 0):

You need to kick-in validation, and only if passed, do the rest.

```
var valid = function () {...}  // validation

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent native submit
    if (valid) {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
          target: 'myResultsDiv'
      })
    }
});
```